# Troubles calling defined function in another defined function

Tags: python, function

Pretty new to coding but I've been learning with Sololearn, YouTube and Google(mainly here on stack overflow). Attempting to make an easy shooting game but my shoot function won't take my result variable to call hit, miss or both. Again sorry but I'm new. This is only the the bare bones of what I want it to be but I can't even get past this stage.

***Writing the code within Sololearn and for some reason I wasn't able to copy the error msg so I attached a picture.[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HctAh.png)

```
playpoints = int(0)
comppoints = int(0)
playhealth = int(100)
comphealth = int(100)
play = input("Would you like to play a game? (Y//N)")

import random
player = random.randint(0, 10)
comp = random.randint(0,10)

def hit(player, comp):
    if player > comp:
        playpoints += 10
        comppoints -= 5
        comphealth -= 10
        result = hit
        return result

def miss(player, comp):
    if player < comp:
        playpoints -= 5
        playhealth -= 10
        comppoints += 10
        result = miss
        return result
def both(player, comp):
    if player == comp:
        comphealth -= 10
        comppoints -= 5
        playhealth -= 10
        playpoints -= 5
        result = both
        return result
    
def shoot(result):
    if result == hit:
            print("You shot me!\n")
            print("Health Totals:\n" + "You: " + str(playhealth) + " Me: "+ str(comphealth))
    
    elif miss:
        print("Yes! I got you!")
        print("Health Totals:\n" + "You: " + str(playhealth) + " Me: "+ str(comphealth))
       
    else:
        both()
        print("What are the odds of that!")
        print("Health Totals:\n" + "You: " + str(playhealth) + " Me: "+ str(comphealth))
          
if play == str("y"):
   shoot()
   
   
print("Points\n"+"You: " + str(playpoints) + "Me:" + str(comppoints) )
```

Comment: You need braces to call a function containing the function arguments - e.g. `hit(player, comp)`

Comment: Please copy the text of the error message (the entire traceback) into your question. Links to images of text are very unhelpful.

Comment: As the error says, on line 50, you do not provide an argument to the function `shoot`, therefore the script crashes.

Comment: I'm new but 'braces' is just parentheses correct? Eg ```shoot(hit(), miss() or both())``` or am I still misunderstanding?